# Converting ios app to 64-bit architecture | Build architecture settings | Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, arm, 32bit-64bit

i am trying to convert my ios app for 64-bit architecture. I am facing little confusion while doing this.

I have removed the warnings and followed the guidelines as mentioned on apple developers. But while changing the architecture to 64-bit in project build setting, i am having confusion i.e. acc to me the app already supports 64-bit architecture.

In buildsetting->architectures: the selected architecture is **"Standard architectures(armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)"**

and valid architecture is: **"arm64 armv7 armv7s"**
Kindly tell me if i'm right or not

Comment: If architecture and valid architecture fields are filled as you have stated, then yes, your app already supports 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under those build settings a 64 bit build will be created as well as a 32 bit. With those build settings you should be fine to upload your build and be covered for both architectures